# Reside: "in" or "on"?

Tags: prepositions

In a clause like this one:

*the success of the book resides in the clear explanations of complex subjects*

is "*in*" the right preposition? Or is it better to use "*on*", like in:

*the success of the book resides on the clear explanations of complex subjects*

Thanks!

Comment: resides in, rests on/upon.

Comment: *...stems **from**, lies **with**, arises **through**...*

Comment: Neither.  One might say "The success of the book resides in *its* clear explanations of complex subjects", but "rests in" would be better, as would several other wordings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In" is better, as one resides in a location rather than on it. However, I don't think that "resides" is a good choice in the first place; perhaps "depends upon" or "is due to"? "Success" requires a source, not a residence.

Comment: I reside in a house. I reside on an island. I reside in a nation. I reside on a continent. I reside on a planet. In what manner something resides depends on context. Is it a surface? An enclosure? An abstract idea? A political entity?

Answer (score 0):

phrasal verb [transitive] *reside in*

```
to exist in or belong to someone or something
Synonyms and related words
To be in a particular position or place:occupy, set, exist...
```

re-side′
v. re•side (rɪˈzaɪd)

v.i. -sid•ed, -sid•ing.
1. to dwell permanently or for a considerable time; live.
2. (of things, qualities, etc.) to be present habitually; be inherent (usu. fol. by in).
3. to rest or be vested, as powers or rights (usu. fol. by in).
[1425–75; late Middle English < Middle French resider < Latin residēre=re- re- + -sidēre, comb. form of sedēre to sit]

"The finest acoustics that can be found in the world reside **in** this hall."

Obversely, in the sciences: " ... we conclude from these results that the functional CaR resides **on** the cell surface of transfected HEK293 cells in the form of a dimer." https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9722601